Do other countries aside from Israel have some special requirements on wearing seatbelt upon approaching destination but before the aircraft descent?
I read  (mirror) that Israel has enhanced security procedures resulting in airplane  passengers having to wear seatbelt up to 180 nautical miles before the destination:

ISRAEL - TEL AVIV FIR
— Enhanced security procedures
• From before reaching the identification point (see below) until after landing: Switch on the ’Fasten Seatbelts’ sign and do not open the cockpit door except for safety reasons.

The identification point (map) can be up to 180 nautical miles before the destination:

• Overflying flights from Amman: The above procedure applies from TKOF until exiting the FIR.
— MIL identification by Tel Aviv CTL
• E-bound: Before 180 NM from Ben Gurion 'BGN', call Tel Aviv Identification 124.300 (sec. 132.050).
• From Amman: Before 10 NM east of TALMI or SALAM, call Tel Aviv CTL 121.400 or 132.050.
• Northbound via R650: At least 10 min before Sharm-El-Sheikh 'SHM', call South Identification 122.850
or 132.000. Maintain at or above FL120, unless cleared otherwise.

Do other countries aside from Israel have some special requirements on wearing seatbelt upon the approaching destination but before the aircraft descent?

Reddit user aries_burner_809 mentioned a similar requirement for DCA airport:

After 9/11, in the USA, the FAA implemented a 30 minute rule at DCA that mandated no standing in the plane for the first 30 mins out, and final 30 mins into the airport. DCA is inside the National Capital Region. That rule was ended.

